# Is there a way to swap screen with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Is it possible to swap screen between monitors? 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 , with hotkey? I’m looking to swap the entire screen.

I found a lot of software like Winsplit, DualMon(SwapScreen) and SwapMon , but all those applications the only thing they do is to change the position of an active windows.

But I’m looking for to swap the entire screen. SwapScreen has an option to change the position to the other screen but crash, and also didn’t work with full screen apps.

My current setup are two monitor as extended, Nvidia graphics card, and I just want to be able to swap with a hotkey the Screen 1 (Mon1) to Mon 2 and viceversa

My second screen is the TV on my living room, where I put videos or games, but sometimes I just want to see something on my first monitor (the monitor on my room), and I don’t want to go there just to check a quick thing.

I don't want to mirror my screen because sometimes I’m on my PC and somebody is on the living room watching a movie or something on the extended monitor.

I know that software like Media Center and everything but i like the way is setup now.

Answer (score 1):

#### Work around that may work in certain situations:

You can move a window on monitor 1 to monitor 2 or vice versa using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.
This effectively moves the focused window to the other screen. Then press

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the other window and perform the previously mentioned keyboard shortcut, to move it to the other screen.

You could then put this in a simple auto-hotkey script of sorts assigned to a shortcut key.

So basically, these 3 key combinations in order:

1. Move focused window to previous/next screen: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>
2. Cycle to next focused window: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Move newly focused window to the other screen: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>

#### Some caveats:

May need to be tweaked for a different number of windows or screens.

Multiple key-shortcuts, or the need for an auxiliary script.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping between two monitors can be done quite easily if they are connected as a computer screen and projector with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Somewhat similar to switching windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can choose to switch to Computer Only, Extend (virtually make one screen of them, with the ability to drag windows from one to the other), Duplicate (both screens show the same window simultaniously), or Projector Only.

Comment: thank for the suggestion, i didn't now about that, but doesn't has the solution im looking for, probably i need to specify that on my question, but my current setup are two monitor as extended and i just want to be able to swap with a hotkey the Screen 1 (Mon1) to Mon 2 and viceversa

Comment: I have a TV and two desk screens attached to my pc. I switch between the desk screens and the tv using batch files which use DisplaySwitch.exe  (in C:\Windows\System32\). `DisplaySwitch.exe /external` switches to my desk, and `DisplaySwitch.exe /internal` switches to my TV. The screens enabled with /external and /internal differ based on the port they are attached to.

Comment: i tried with that but is the same as WinKey + P