# Is there a shortcut to swap two windows on multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I have 2 monitors and sometimes I want to put window1 on the left monitor and window2 on the right monitor. Sometimes I want to swap this, e.g. put window2 on the left monitor and window1 on the right monitor. Is there a shortcut for this? Currently I am using drag and drop. Similar question was asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/594283/is-there-a-way-to-swap-screen) but I am using Windows 7.

Comment: When you say "Window" are you referring to the display itself or a program window?

Comment: Program window in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding the question right, you should be able to accomplish this buy holding `Windows Key + Shift` and then pushing the appropriate `Arrow Key` to which direction or monitor you want the window to populate.

You can also "*Snap*" windows to the left or right halves of your screen by holding `Windows Key` and then pressing the appropriate `Arrow Key` in the direction you are looking to snap.

Bear in mind that you must select the windows you are trying to move individually.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I only knew <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Key</kbd> before. I will try that tomorrow at work.

Comment: @MSC Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Down vote, due to limited answer does not cover all scenarios

Comment: @dExIT I answered the question appropriately and as accurately as I could provided by info of the question.  Please elaborate how this answer is "Limited".  There are many solutions to everything, feel free to also provide some yourself.

Comment: @dExIT: Just don't say anything if you have nothing to contribute. Cheesus Crust: Works, was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not built into Windows, no. Not even in Windows 10. The answer you linked switches the entire desktop between screens (and then only when supported as such by your hardware and configuration... which doesn't sound applicable here).

You might look into [Display Fusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/). It's an incredibly powerful suite of utilities for managing multi-monitor configurations (even has a scripting engine based on C# and VB). Best of all, perhaps, is the community support. If you need specific functionality, as in your case, and there isn't already a script/feature that does it you can ask on their forums and someone will usually create a custom script for you (which you can then assign to the shortcut-keys of your choice).

Unfortunately, the juiciest features are only available in the pay version, but there is a trial that will let you try it out and see if it will work for you, and the price isn't that high considering all it can do.